# no such file or directory, stat 'C:\idora-photobok\backend\frontend\build\index.html'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

So, I got this error while try to ready my application for production. So, my index.js code is

```
const app = express();
const port = 8000;
const cors = require('cors');
const db=require('./config/mongoose');
const path = require('path')

//library used
const passport = require('passport');
const passportJWT = require('./config/passport-jwt-strategy');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');



//middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
//use routes
app.use('/', require('./routes'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/frontend/build')))

app.get('*', (req, res) => 
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html')))

app.listen(port, async function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(`error in running of server;${err}`);
    }
  console.log(`server is running on port:${port}`);
    });
```

[image]

This is my file structure. So, If someone know, why this is happening. please reply.

Thanks

Comment: The error message means the file `C:\idora-photobok\backend\frontend\build\index.html` doesn't exist.   The backend\frontend part is weird.  Are you running this in the directory you expected?

Comment: I also think there is backend\ there, but don't have any idea.

Comment: The image does not show the expected path either

Comment: And I am running this in root directory. Idora

Comment: Ok, So if this information is not sufficient. I can share more. Just tell me